# UIView as a header for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm learning iOS programming in swift by the book "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (6th Edition)", but it seems a little outdated. I encountered a problem with adding a header to UIViewTable in Storyboard. 
In the book, it suggested to add an UIView on top of prototype cell, place buttons there with constraints and that's all, but in my case, that doesn't work. Buttons won't show up :(
So, it looks like this:
[image]

Could you help me with this example, please?

My ItemsViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemStore: ItemStore!

    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if isEditing {
            sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
            setEditing(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            setEditing(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return itemStore.allItems.count + 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        if itemStore.allItems.count == indexPath.row {

            cell.textLabel?.text = "No more items"
        } else {

            let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

UPD: I have done that programmatically through `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`, but it's not convenient.
Is there any way to achieve the same effect with the storyboard way?

Comment: Can you add "tableView.tableHeaderView" or header height and check.

Comment: Please post what does your `ItemsViewController.swift` looks like because I tried the same thing you have there and the view on top appears correctly in my simulator

Comment: Sure, I have added my ItemsViewController.swift to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of all evil. If you're setting up the ItemStore like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = (scene as! UIWindowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = ItemsViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Create an ItemStore
    let itemStore = ItemStore()

    // Access the ItemsViewController and set its item store
    let itemsController = window!.rootViewController as! ItemsViewController
    itemsController.itemStore = itemStore
}
```

Do not do that. For me works this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    itemStore = ItemStore()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65
}
```

The book seems vastly outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related with `headerViewSize` size. Please, try something like below.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guard let tableHeaderView = tableView.tableHeaderView else { return }
    let size = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    if tableHeaderView.frame.size.height != size.height {
        tableHeaderView.frame.size.height = size.height
    }
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
}
```

Comment: Not working :( If I understand this correctly, this code depends on setting tableHeaderView property, which I don't set. What's the proper way to do that? I have tried to make an Outlet for my UIVIew and then `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView` in viewDidLoad(), but that didn't help.

Comment: I did something very similar. I added a UILabel for headerview as you did in the storyboard and used above function to calculate its size. Just try to wrap all of them in one view and have a strong referance in the viewController to that view. It might be the problem you are having. Also, would you mind checking whether you receive a `tableView.tableHeaderView` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or not.

Comment: It seems I'm doing something very wrong. Now it fails with `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` on the line `return itemStore.allItems.count + 1`. I have checked the debugger, the variable `var itemStore: ItemStore!` is always _nil_, if add `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`. I have no clue how it's related :(

Comment: Just try to clean your project and your derived data. It may help.